# Is there a listener for Android app widget permission changes?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-6.0-marshmallow, smartphone

I've been working on an app widget for Android 6 and how it works is that every time the Broadcast Receiver receives an onUpdate, it will check for permissions before updating the RemoteView with the appropriate contents such as a message saying, "permissions missing" or whatever it's supposed to have.

However, I notice that if I disable any of the permissions my app requires via System > App > Permissions the process gets marked as "dead" in Studio.

If I then test if the widget still works in the emulator by triggering an onUpdate, sure enough it's not working any more. As soon as I toggle the permissions back on, a new process ID is generated and the widget is alive and working again.

Now my question is, is there a way to capture that change in permissions? It's weird that the widget is still "alive" on the home screen when it's supposed to be "dead" according to Studio (with no errors thrown it seems...) due to a permissions change =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I think I've figured out the problem...

When a user goes into a phone's setting > apps > app > permissions and then revokes permissions, it ends up killing the app's process - or it might actually be suspended somewhere because as soon as you grant a permission again, the same process (same PID) is alive again.

As a result of this, the widget IDs are lost so onUpdate() isn't called when the broadcast is received and all the widgets that have been added to the home screen can't be updated.

So, the workaround?

Fetch a new instance of AppWidgetManager and manually put those widget IDs back into the Intent before super.onReceive() is called. Then you will be able to access all the widget instances again and update them accordingly.

```java
@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

    String action = i.getAction();
    if ( action.equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE) ) {
        ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName(c,     BroadcastHandler.class);
         AppWidgetManager am = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
         int[] ids = am.getAppWidgetIds(thiswidget);
         i.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);

        // either handle the permission change at this point or in onUpdate()
    }

    super.onReceive(c,i);

}
```

I don't know why Google doesn't have a permissions revoked listener to be honest =/

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if thats exactly what you are looking for, but i used this code to check for permissions. If the permission was declined, the next time you use the app (wearable app in my case), it will ask again for permission.

I used this function in a extra class, so maybe you should modify it to fit.

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mainActivity,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);

        if (permissionCheck != 0) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                mainActivity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION);
            }
        }
```

as well you have to declare a final variable

```
private final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION=1;
```

you have to replace the line Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO with Manifest.permission.(your permission)

If you want to check the permission frequently - make a methode and use it in your code before the permission is required.

Hope i could help you

Birki

Comment: The problem is is what happens after the permissions are granted. If I manually toggle the permissions off via phone's settings, the app widget stops working on the home screen and the process shows up as dead with no errors - that's what I'm trying to catch =/